# Want to copy text file from local drive to server location using groovy script. Getting missing method exception

Tags: groovy, soapui

Below is my script:

```
def FilePath = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("FOLDER_PATH") 
def FileName = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("FILE_NAME") 
def file = new File(FilePath+"\\"+FileName) 
log.info(file)
def destination = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("FILE_DEPOSITORY")
log.info(destination)
if(file.exists()) 
{  
    file.copyfile(FileName,FilePath,destination) 
} else 
{  
    log.info("A file named " + FileName + " does not exisits at the path "+FilePath)  
}
```

Below exception I am getting:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.File.copyfile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [filename, sourepath, destination path] Possible solutions: isFile() error at line: 15

Comment: Show us the value in `FilePath`

Comment: What implements `copyFile(...)`?  I don't see that in java.io.File nor the groovy extensions for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested locally and working,

```
def Source = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("FOLDER_PATH")
def FileName = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("FILE_NAME")
def AbsoluteSource = new File(Source + "\\" + FileName)
def Destination = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("DESTINATION")
def AbsoluteDestination = new File(Destination + "\\" + FileName)
if (AbsoluteSource.exists()) {
 AbsoluteDestination << AbsoluteSource.bytes
} else {
 log.info("A file named " + FileName + " does not exisits at the path " + Source)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I am getting below error now: java.io.FileNotFoundException: [DestinationPath]\I[FileName] (The network name cannot be found) error at line: 16

Comment: I just want to pick file from my local drive and drop to the server location. Further the file get automatically processed and moved to another folder.

Comment: The error is clear, "FileNotFound", Is the location correct and the file present ?

Comment: Yes. file is present at the source location. And error is saying file not found at the destination location, not clear about this as we are dropping file at server location.

Comment: As I see def AbsoluteDestination = new File(destination + "\\" + FileName) . Here we are giving file name in absoluteDestination may the cause of this error As I have not kept that file at server location. Reason is that when I drop/keep file at this server location then file get picked automatically and processed and moved to other folder immediatly.

Comment: You don't need to have a file at the server location, This copies the file from source location and pastes it in the same name in server location. Let me know if it doesn't work and we can setup a WebEx and try it out if you want

Comment: Hi @Wilfred Clement, thank you for your help. Above solution worked for me as there was small mistake in the server path because of which I was getting an error "Network path error". Thanks :)